# PHP - Getting values inside PHP tags

Tags: php

I have a HTML page that includes the code

```
<li><span class="li-time">00:30</span>
<span class="li-title">Headline News</span></li>
<li><span class="li-time">00:31</span>
<span class="li-title">Money Mind</span></li>
<li><span class="li-time">01:00</span>
<span class="li-title">Headline News</span></li>
<li><span class="li-time">01:01</span>
<span class="li-title">Singapore Tonight</span></li>
```

and does not have a definite number of how many values there are. What I want to do is to format the result so that it displays all of the time/title in the format

```
00:30 Headline News
00:31 Money Mind
01:00 Headline News
```

It would be best if I didn't have to use an external parser. Sorta new to php, hope you guys can advise me :)

Comment: So you have a bunch of times, and a bunch of names, and they are associated with each other on a 1-to-1 basis? This data should be expressed as a table.

Comment: Why do you want to use PHP to transform HTML? Use CSS to style the page into the presentation you want.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is though. Is that HTML the input or the output? Where does PHP come into it? Do you want to parse the HTML with PHP, and then output a plain text file with the data?

Comment: That's HTML, not php. I would suggest finding a good online tutorial on starting php

Comment: The HTML is an external page not controlled by me. What I want to do is to take in the source code and get all the values, which I've managed to do and then format the results

Comment: Assuming you're trying to extract the plaintext: Take a look at DOM extension of PHP. :) http://php.net/dom

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: Thanks for the tip to use DOM, helped alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this simple case, just call `$text = strip_tags($html)`. Then `$text` looks like this:

```
00:30
Headline News
00:31
Money Mind
01:00
Headline News
```

Now do something like this to replace every other newline with a space:

```
$lines = explode('\n',$text);
$final_text = '';
for ($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++) {
  $final_text .= $lines[$i];
  if ($i%2==0) {
     $final_text .= ' ';
  } else {
     $final_text .='\n';
  }
}
```

If the HTML you have is not always precisely the format you have shown, you will have to parse the HTML using [SimpleXML](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) or the more complicated [DOM functions](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/domimplementation.createdocument.php).

An example using SimpleXML would be the following:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<html>
<li><span class="li-time">00:30</span>
<span class="li-title">Headline News</span></li>
<li><span class="li-time">00:31</span>
<span class="li-title">Money Mind</span></li>
<li><span class="li-time">01:00</span>
<span class="li-title">Headline News</span></li>
<li><span class="li-time">01:01</span>
<span class="li-title">Singapore Tonight</span></li> 
</html>
EOF;

$sx = simplexml_load_string($html);

$output_text = '';
foreach($sx->li as $list_item) {
    $output_text .= $list_item->span[0] . " " . $list_item->span[1] . "\n";
}

echo $output_text;
```

Please note that $html must be wrapped with some tag (I chose `<html></html>` in the example).

Comment: I've tried the `split_tags` function already, but the results actually turn out to be `00:30Headline News00:31Money Mind01:00Headline News` instead of new lines

Comment: Oh... Have you tried adding a space before every newline? Eg. `str_replace('\n',' \n',$text)`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the suggestions guys, managed to solve my problem using DOM

```
<?php


$data = file_get_contents("html");


$pattern = '/<ul id="schedule">.*<\/ul>/';
preg_match($pattern, $data, $matches); // to obtain sample code (<li><span...>)


function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname){
    $d = new DOMDocument();
    $d->loadHTML($string);
    $return = array();
    foreach($d->getElementsByTagName($tagname) as $item){
        $return[] = $item->textContent;
    }
    return $return;
}

$count = 0;
$txt = getTextBetweenTags($matches[0], "span");
foreach ($txt as $val){
$count++;
echo $val;
echo "\t";
if (($count % 2) == 0){
    print "<br>";
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to control layout and typography, you have to use CSS, not PHP.

Comment: So I won't be able to format it using php even if I've stored the HTML code in a variable? I'm getting the results(time/title) from another site, so it's not possible to use HTML/CSS for formatting.